# Sanctum laravel is working fine on local, not in heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-sanctum

I have developed a front (react) and a back (php laravel) with the authentication system "sanctum". All is working fine on localhost. But I can't get it to work in production in heroku.

In local environment ,my .env is (extract) :

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000,127.0.0.1:3000,localhost:8000,127.0.0.1:8000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
```

If I have understood well, the front and back must be on the same domains for the cookies. As my back and front are hosted in heroku (herokuapp.com), I have these .env :

[image]

But with this configuration, I always have a response **419 CSRF token mismatch**.

Certainly my conf is not correct. But I tried a lot of things without success.

**edit :**

The back url is: https://school-back-v2.herokuapp.com/

The front url is: https://react-protected-routes.herokuapp.com/

Comment: But your site is not hosted on herokyapp.com it's hosted on a subdomain of herokyapp. It would be bad if any app hosted on heroku had access to your user's cookies

Comment: I have added the urls for the back and front. So in your opinion, what should be the configuration with these urls in the . env ?

Comment: The cookie for the backend should be under domain `school-back-v2.herokuapp.com`. `Secure` should be true and [SameSite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) should be set to `None`

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is blacklisted by browsers to use cookie if you site placed on Heroku subdomain. You can use Heroku, but must to register your own domain and use it, so that resolve this problem.
Other variant - use tokens instead cookie.